# Splitting strings in Apache Spark using Scala

Tags: string, scala, apache-spark

I have a dataset, which contains lines in the format (tab separated):

```
Title<\t>Text
```

Now for every word in `Text`, I want to create a `(Word,Title)` pair. 
For instance:

```
ABC      Hello World
```

gives me

```
(Hello, ABC)
(World, ABC)
```

Using Scala, I wrote the following:

```
val file = sc.textFile("s3n://file.txt")
val title = file.map(line => line.split("\t")(0))
val wordtitle = file.map(line => (line.split("\t")(1).split(" ").map(word => (word, line.split("\t")(0)))))
```

But this gives me the following output:

```
[Lscala.Tuple2;@2204b589
[Lscala.Tuple2;@632a46d1
[Lscala.Tuple2;@6c8f7633
[Lscala.Tuple2;@3e9945f3
[Lscala.Tuple2;@40bf74a0
[Lscala.Tuple2;@5981d595
[Lscala.Tuple2;@5aed571b
[Lscala.Tuple2;@13f1dc40
[Lscala.Tuple2;@6bb2f7fa
[Lscala.Tuple2;@32b67553
[Lscala.Tuple2;@68d0b627
[Lscala.Tuple2;@8493285
```

How do I solve this?

**Further reading**

What I want to achieve is to count the number of `Words` that occur in a `Text` for a particular `Title`.

The subsequent code that I have written is:

```
val wordcountperfile = file.map(line => (line.split("\t")(1).split(" ").flatMap(word => word), line.split("\t")(0))).map(word => (word, 1)).reduceByKey(_ + _)
```

But it does not work. Please feel free to give your inputs on this. Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

So... In spark you work using distributed data structure called RDD. They provide functionality similar to scala's collection types.

```
val fileRdd = sc.textFile("s3n://file.txt")
// RDD[ String ]

val splitRdd = fileRdd.map( line => line.split("\t") )
// RDD[ Array[ String ]

val yourRdd = splitRdd.flatMap( arr => {
  val title = arr( 0 )
  val text = arr( 1 )
  val words = text.split( " " )
  words.map( word => ( word, title ) )
} )
// RDD[ ( String, String ) ]

// Now, if you want to print this...
yourRdd.foreach( { case ( word, title ) => println( s"{ $word, $title }" ) } )

// if you want to count ( this count is for non-unique words), 
val countRdd = yourRdd
  .groupBy( { case ( word, title ) => title } )  // group by title
  .map( { case ( title, iter ) => ( title, iter.size ) } ) // count for every title
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick post. However, it gives me an error or seq.length. Basically, I want to store the ((Word,Title), COUNT) in a file.

Comment: I'm using this to count the words: 
val countRdd = yourRdd.map(title => (title, 1)).reduceByKey(_ + _)

Can you confirm it's correct.

Comment: Yes... because `Iterable` does not have `length`... they have `size`. Changing the answer.

Comment: Yes... your reduceByKey approach is also Ok. I am giving you number of words per title. So... `( title, count )`.

Answer (score 3):

This is how it can be solved using the **newer dataframe API**. First read the data using "\t" as a delimiter:

```
val df = spark.read
  .option("delimiter", "\t")
  .option("header", false)
  .csv("s3n://file.txt")
  .toDF("title", "text")
```

Then, `split` the `text` column on space and `explode` to get one word per row.

```
val df2 = df.select($"title", explode(split($"text", " ")).as("words"))
```

Finally, group on the `title` column and count the number of words for each.

```
val countDf = df2.groupBy($"title").agg(count($"words"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another version with DataFrame API

```scala
// read into DataFrame
val viewsDF=spark.read.text("s3n://file.txt")

// Split
val splitedViewsDF = viewsDF.withColumn("col1", split($"value", "\\t").getItem(0)).withColumn("col2", split($"value", "\\s+").getItem(1)).drop($"value"))
```

### Sample

```
scala> val viewsDF=spark.read.text("spark-labs/data/wiki-pageviews.txt")
viewsDF: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [value: string]

scala> viewsDF.printSchema
root
 |-- value: string (nullable = true)


scala> viewsDF.limit(5).show
+------------------+
|             value|
+------------------+
|  aa Main_Page 3 0|
|  aa Main_page 1 0|
|  aa User:Savh 1 0|
|  aa Wikipedia 1 0|
|aa.b User:Savh 1 0|
+------------------+


scala> val splitedViewsDF = viewsDF.withColumn("col1", split($"value", "\\s+").getItem(0)).withColumn("col2", split($"value", "\\s+").getItem(1)).withColumn("col3", split($"value", "\\s+").getItem(2)).drop($"value")
splitedViewsDF: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [col1: string, col2: string ... 1 more field]

scala>

scala> splitedViewsDF.printSchema
root
 |-- col1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- col2: string (nullable = true)
 |-- col3: string (nullable = true)


scala> splitedViewsDF.limit(5).show
+----+---------+----+
|col1|     col2|col3|
+----+---------+----+
|  aa|Main_Page|   3|
|  aa|Main_page|   1|
|  aa|User:Savh|   1|
|  aa|Wikipedia|   1|
|aa.b|User:Savh|   1|
+----+---------+----+


scala>
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer which proved above is not good enough.
`.map( line => line.split("\t") )` may cause:

> org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 18.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 18.0 (TID 1485, ip-172-31-113-181.us-west-2.compute.internal, executor 10): java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while encoding: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 14

in case the last column is empty.
the best result explained here -
[Split 1 column into 3 columns in spark scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39255973/split-1-column-into-3-columns-in-spark-scala)