# Split 1 column into 3 columns in spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a dataframe in Spark using scala that has a column that I need split.

```
scala> test.show
+-------------+
|columnToSplit|
+-------------+
|        a.b.c|
|        d.e.f|
+-------------+
```

I need this column split out to look like this:

```
+--------------+
|col1|col2|col3|
|   a|   b|   c|
|   d|   e|   f|
+--------------+
```

I'm using Spark 2.0.0

Thanks

Answer (score 99, accepted):

Try:

```
import sparkObject.spark.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.split

df.withColumn("_tmp", split($"columnToSplit", "\\.")).select(
  $"_tmp".getItem(0).as("col1"),
  $"_tmp".getItem(1).as("col2"),
  $"_tmp".getItem(2).as("col3")
)
```

The important point to note here is that the `sparkObject` is the SparkSession object you might have already initialized. So, the (1) import statement has to be compulsorily put inline within the code, not before the class definition.

Comment: Works great, Thanks!

Comment: what import is required for split?

Comment: @Jake import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.split use this

Comment: @Surendra Pratap thank you! i was searched 30 min for that :)

Comment: `import spark.implicits._` to use the $-notation.

Comment: Just additional info, you use \\ before . for escaping.

Comment: using \\ slashes does the magic without that it does not work. Thanks

Comment: Please avoid using indexes for getting the values out. Such a solution is never going to be dynamic. For this simple case with 3 columns, this is fine, but it does not look good or dynamic enough for more number of columns!

Answer (score 44):

To do this programmatically, you can create a sequence of expressions with `(0 until 3).map(i => col("temp").getItem(i).as(s"col$i"))` (assume you need 3 columns as result) and then apply it to `select` with `: _*` syntax:

```
df.withColumn("temp", split(col("columnToSplit"), "\\.")).select(
    (0 until 3).map(i => col("temp").getItem(i).as(s"col$i")): _*
).show
+----+----+----+
|col0|col1|col2|
+----+----+----+
|   a|   b|   c|
|   d|   e|   f|
+----+----+----+
```

---

To keep all columns:

```
df.withColumn("temp", split(col("columnToSplit"), "\\.")).select(
    col("*") +: (0 until 3).map(i => col("temp").getItem(i).as(s"col$i")): _*
).show
+-------------+---------+----+----+----+
|columnToSplit|     temp|col0|col1|col2|
+-------------+---------+----+----+----+
|        a.b.c|[a, b, c]|   a|   b|   c|
|        d.e.f|[d, e, f]|   d|   e|   f|
+-------------+---------+----+----+----+
```

---

If you are using `pyspark`, use a list comprehension to replace the `map` in scala:

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame([['a.b.c'], ['d.e.f']], ['columnToSplit'])
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, split

(df.withColumn('temp', split('columnToSplit', '\\.'))
   .select(*(col('temp').getItem(i).alias(f'col{i}') for i in range(3))
).show()
+----+----+----+
|col0|col1|col2|
+----+----+----+
|   a|   b|   c|
|   d|   e|   f|
+----+----+----+
```

Comment: Can we split to the arbitrary number of columns? Why 3 has to be hardcoded?

Comment: I have similar scenario, but number of "." separated values are unknown. how can we split the rows dynamically?

Comment: There are multiple nice answers here because they each break things down a little further, but if you have a lot of columns or a lot of dataframes to do this with (for example reading many topics from Kafka), then this answer is the way to go.

Comment: How does the first answer (the not all columns version) translate in pyspark/python?

Comment: I created another answer to show how to implement this approach without hardcoding the number of columns.

Answer (score 19):

A solution which avoids the select part. This is helpful when you just want to append the new columns:

```
case class Message(others: String, text: String)

val r1 = Message("foo1", "a.b.c")
val r2 = Message("foo2", "d.e.f")

val records = Seq(r1, r2)
val df = spark.createDataFrame(records)

df.withColumn("col1", split(col("text"), "\\.").getItem(0))
  .withColumn("col2", split(col("text"), "\\.").getItem(1))
  .withColumn("col3", split(col("text"), "\\.").getItem(2))
  .show(false)

+------+-----+----+----+----+
|others|text |col1|col2|col3|
+------+-----+----+----+----+
|foo1  |a.b.c|a   |b   |c   |
|foo2  |d.e.f|d   |e   |f   |
+------+-----+----+----+----+
```

**Update:** I highly recommend to use [Psidom's implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45972636/1646364) to avoid splitting three times.

Answer (score 9):

This appends columns to the original DataFrame and doesn't use `select`, and only splits once using a temporary column:

```
import spark.implicits._

df.withColumn("_tmp", split($"columnToSplit", "\\."))
  .withColumn("col1", $"_tmp".getItem(0))
  .withColumn("col2", $"_tmp".getItem(1))
  .withColumn("col3", $"_tmp".getItem(2))
  .drop("_tmp")
```

Answer (score 5):

This expands on Psidom's answer and shows how to do the split dynamically, without hardcoding the number of columns.  This answer runs a query to calculate the number of columns.

```
val df = Seq(
  "a.b.c",
  "d.e.f"
).toDF("my_str")
.withColumn("letters", split(col("my_str"), "\\."))

val numCols = df
  .withColumn("letters_size", size($"letters"))
  .agg(max($"letters_size"))
  .head()
  .getInt(0)

df
  .select(
    (0 until numCols).map(i => $"letters".getItem(i).as(s"col$i")): _*
  )
  .show()
```

Answer (score 2):

We can write using for with yield in Scala :-

If your number of columns exceeds just add it to desired column and play with it. :)

```
val aDF = Seq("Deepak.Singh.Delhi").toDF("name")
val desiredColumn = Seq("name","Lname","City")
val colsize = desiredColumn.size

val columList = for (i <- 0 until colsize) yield split(col("name"),".").getItem(i).alias(desiredColumn(i))

aDF.select(columList: _ *).show(false)
```

Output:-

```
+------+------+-----+--+
|name  |Lname |city |
+-----+------+-----+---+
|Deepak|Singh |Delhi|
+---+------+-----+-----+
```

If you don't need name column then, drop the column and  just use withColumn.

Answer (score 0):

Example:
Without using the select statement.

Lets assume we have a dataframe having a set of columns and we want to split a column having column name as **name**

```
import spark.implicits._

val columns = Seq("name","age","address")

val data = Seq(("Amit.Mehta", 25, "1 Main st, Newark, NJ, 92537"),
             ("Rituraj.Mehta", 28,"3456 Walnut st, Newark, NJ, 94732"))

var dfFromData = spark.createDataFrame(data).toDF(columns:_*)
dfFromData.printSchema()

val newDF = dfFromData.map(f=>{
val nameSplit = f.getAs[String](0).split("\\.").map(_.trim)
      (nameSplit(0),nameSplit(1),f.getAs[Int](1),f.getAs[String](2))
    })

val finalDF = newDF.toDF("First Name","Last Name", "Age","Address")

finalDF.printSchema()

finalDF.show(false)
```

output:
[image: output]