# Spark doesn't read columns with null values in first row

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-2.0, spark-csv

Below is the content in my csv  file :

```
A1,B1,C1
A2,B2,C2,D1
A3,B3,C3,D2,E1
A4,B4,C4,D3
A5,B5,C5,,E2
```

So, there are 5 columns but only 3 values in the first row.

I read it using the following command :

```
val csvDF : DataFrame = spark.read
.option("header", "false")
.option("delimiter", ",")
.option("inferSchema", "false")
.csv("file.csv")
```

And following is what i get using csvDF.show()

```
+---+---+---+
|_c0|_c1|_c2|
+---+---+---+
| A1| B1| C1|
| A2| B2| C2|
| A3| B3| C3|
| A4| B4| C4|
| A5| B5| C5|
+---+---+---+
```

How can i read all the data in all the columns?

Comment: is it possible to add all 5 columns to each row? Like for row 1 instead of A1,B1,C1 have it be A1,B1,C1,,

Comment: That's only a workaround, and will not work if the csv is managed by someone else.

Comment: Just specify schema manually

Comment: what if we don't know the schema, the content in the csv in not know in advance.

Comment: All content in csv can be specified as StringType

Comment: This is not even a proper csv. You don't have delimiters(commas) for the other two columns in the first line. You can try creating a custom schema, loading the file using `sc.textFile` and checking if each row has number of columns equal to what you have in the schema.

Answer (score 1):

Basically your csv-file isn't properly formatted in the sense that it doesn't have a equal number of columns in each row, which is required if you want to read it with `spark.read.csv`. However, you can instead read it with `spark.read.textFile` and then parse each row.

As I understand it, you do not know the number of columns beforehand, so you want your code to handle an arbitrary number of columns. To do this you need to establish the maximum number of columns in your data set, so you need two passes over your data set.

For this particular problem, I would actually go with RDDs instead of DataFrames or Datasets, like this:

```
val data  = spark.read.textFile("file.csv").rdd

val rdd = data.map(s => (s, s.split(",").length)).cache
val maxColumns = rdd.map(_._2).max()

val x = rdd
  .map(row => {
    val rowData = row._1.split(",")
    val extraColumns = Array.ofDim[String](maxColumns - rowData.length)
    Row((rowData ++ extraColumns).toList:_*)
  })
```

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You can read it as a dataset with only one column (for example by using another delimiter) :

```
var df = spark.read.format("csv").option("delimiter",";").load("test.csv")
df.show()

+--------------+
|           _c0|
+--------------+
|      A1,B1,C1|
|   A2,B2,C2,D1|
|A3,B3,C3,D2,E1|
|   A4,B4,C4,D3|
|  A5,B5,C5,,E2|
+--------------+
```

Then you can use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39256038/4678661) to manually split your column in five, this will add *null* values when the element does not exist :

```
var csvDF = df.withColumn("_tmp",split($"_c0",",")).select(
    $"_tmp".getItem(0).as("col1"),
    $"_tmp".getItem(1).as("col2"),
    $"_tmp".getItem(2).as("col3"),
    $"_tmp".getItem(3).as("col4"),
    $"_tmp".getItem(4).as("col5")
)
csvDF.show()

+----+----+----+----+----+
|col1|col2|col3|col4|col5|
+----+----+----+----+----+
|  A1|  B1|  C1|null|null|
|  A2|  B2|  C2|  D1|null|
|  A3|  B3|  C3|  D2|  E1|
|  A4|  B4|  C4|  D3|null|
|  A5|  B5|  C5|    |  E2|
+----+----+----+----+----+
```

Answer (score 0):

If the column `dataTypes` and number of columns are known then you can define `schema` and apply the `schema` while reading the `csv` file as `dataframe`. Below I have defined all five columns as `stringType`

```
val schema = StructType(Seq(
  StructField("col1", StringType, true),
  StructField("col2", StringType, true),
  StructField("col3", StringType, true),
  StructField("col4", StringType, true),
  StructField("col5", StringType, true)))

val csvDF : DataFrame = sqlContext.read
  .option("header", "false")
  .option("delimiter", ",")
  .option("inferSchema", "false")
  .schema(schema)
  .csv("file.csv")
```

You should be getting `dataframe` as

```
+----+----+----+----+----+
|col1|col2|col3|col4|col5|
+----+----+----+----+----+
|A1  |B1  |C1  |null|null|
|A2  |B2  |C2  |D1  |null|
|A3  |B3  |C3  |D2  |E1  |
|A4  |B4  |C4  |D3  |null|
|A5  |B5  |C5  |null|E2  |
+----+----+----+----+----+
```