# Split string column based on delimiter and create columns for each value in Pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I have 1000s of files with data in the below format:

```
a|b|c|clm4=1|clm5=3
a|b|c|clm4=9|clm6=60|clm7=23
```

And I want to read it and convert it to a dataframe as below:

```
clm1|clm2|clm3|clm4|clm5|clm6|clm7
a|b|c|1|3|null|null
a|b|c|9|null|60|23
```

I have tried the below method:

```
files = [f for f in glob.glob(pathToFile + "/**/*.txt.gz", recursive=True)]
df = spark.read.load(files, format='csv', sep = '|', header=None)
```

But it is giving me below result:

```
clm1, clm2, clm3, clm4, clm5
a, b, c, 1, 3
a, b, c, 9, null
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45605839/spark-doesnt-read-columns-with-null-values-in-first-row

Comment: To use this method I have to write getItem() for each column which is not possible because there are 100s of columns and most of them are unknown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Spark 2.4+, you can read the files as a single column then split it by `|`. You'll get an array column that you could transform using [higher-order functions](https://docs.databricks.com/_static/notebooks/apache-spark-2.4-functions.html):

```
df.show(truncate=False)

+----------------------------+
|clm                         |
+----------------------------+
|a|b|c|clm4=1|clm5=3         |
|a|b|c|clm4=9|clm6=60|clm7=23|
+----------------------------+
```

We use `transform` function to convert the array of string that we get from splitting the `clm` column into an array of structs.
Each struct contains column name if present (check if a string contains `=`) or name it `clm + (i+1)` where `i` is its position.

```
transform_expr = """
transform(split(clm, '[|]'), (x, i) -> 
                   struct(
                         IF(x like '%=%', substring_index(x, '=', 1), concat('clm', i+1)), 
                         substring_index(x, '=', -1)
                         )
        )
"""
```

Now use `map_from_entries` to convert the array to map. And finally, explode the map and pivot to get your columns

```
df.select("clm", 
          explode(map_from_entries(expr(transform_expr))).alias("col_name", "col_value")
         ) \
  .groupby("clm").pivot('col_name').agg(first('col_value')) \
  .drop("clm") \
  .show(truncate=False)
```

Gives:

```
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|clm1|clm2|clm3|clm4|clm5|clm6|clm7|
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|a   |b   |c   |9   |null|60  |23  |
|a   |b   |c   |1   |3   |null|null|
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Is there any way I can put a condition in above code to select only those columns that are present in an existing list of column names?