# dynamically pass arguments to function in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, bigdata

i have record as string with 1000 fields with delimiter as comma  in dataframe like

"a,b,c,d,e.......upto 1000"   -1st record
"p,q,r,s,t ......upto 1000"    - 2nd record

I am using below suggested solution from stackoverflow

[Split 1 column into 3 columns in spark scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39255973/split-1-column-into-3-columns-in-spark-scala)

```
df.withColumn("_tmp", split($"columnToSplit", "\\.")).select($"_tmp".getItem(0).as("col1"),$"_tmp".getItem(1).as("col2"),$"_tmp".getItem(2).as("col3")).drop("_tmp")
```

however in my case i am having 1000 columns which i have in JSON schema which i can retrive like

```
column_seq:Seq[Array]=Schema_func.map(_.name)
for(i <-o to column_seq.length-1){println(i+" " + column_seq(i))}
```

which returns like

0 col1
1 col2 
2 col3
3 col4

Now I need to pass all this indexes and column names  to below function of DataFrame

```
df.withColumn("_tmp", split($"columnToSplit", "\\.")).select($"_tmp".getItem(0).as("col1"),$"_tmp".getItem(1).as("col2"),$"_tmp".getItem(2).as("col3")).drop("_tmp")
```

in

```
$"_tmp".getItem(0).as("col1"),$"_tmp".getItem(1).as("col2"),
```

as i cant create the long statement with all 1000 columns , is there any effective way to pass all this arguments from above mentioned json schema to select function , so that i can split  the columns , add the header and then covert the DF to parquet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build a series of `org.apache.spark.sql.Column`, where each one is the result of selecting the right item and has the right name, and then `select` these columns:

```
val columns: Seq[Column] = Schema_func.map(_.name)
  .zipWithIndex // attach index to names
  .map { case (name, index) => $"_tmp".getItem(index) as name }

val result = df
  .withColumn("_tmp", split($"columnToSplit", "\\."))
  .select(columns: _*)
```

For example, for this input:

```
case class A(name: String)
val Schema_func = Seq(A("c1"), A("c2"), A("c3"), A("c4"), A("c5"))
val df = Seq("a.b.c.d.e").toDF("columnToSplit")
```

The `result` would be:

```
// +---+---+---+---+---+
// | c1| c2| c3| c4| c5|
// +---+---+---+---+---+
// |  a|  b|  c|  d|  e|
// +---+---+---+---+---+
```